# Does the drop_partition command ignore foreign key dependencies?

Tags: vertica

Given table A with column (A1, A2, A3...) and table B with column (B1, B2, A1) where A1 is a foreign key on field A1 in table A.

Table A contains records that are referenced by B.

Tables are partitioned by a date field, and the field has the same value for related records in table A and B.

**If a partition is dropped that contains a row in A that is referenced by B, why do I not get an exception?  I would have expected some kind of error indicating that the record is being referenced somewhere.**

Or am I missing something - should it be warning me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to version 8, Vertica can not enforce primary, unique or foreign key constraints during dml operations. You would have to detect the violation after the fact using `analyze_constraints()`.

Even version 8 has limitations in this regard. First, you have to make sure the checking is enabled. Secondly, this only works for primary and uniques keys.

In order to enforce FK (on either version), you have to create a prejoin projection. However, even doing this is may not be your answer because you can't drop partitions when there is a prejoin projection (you'll have drop the prejoin projection, drop partitions, recreate the prejoin projection).

Also there are some other limitations to using prejoin projections.

I'll also mention that Vertica is not OLTP, it's focus is on fast loading and fast queries (and compression). I understand your pain, though, as occasionally I do need functionality like this.

Hope this helps.